# Not able to get Stringvar()/Intvar()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

1. What should I do to get the values using StringVar() / IntVar(), I'm only getting ''/0
2. Below is my smaller part of code applied to one of the functionalities in my app. Please do tell me what am I missing in my code to retrieve the expected output.

```
 #to add an add product page
    def add_product_page(self):
        new_window = Toplevel(self)
        new_window.geometry("650x550")
        new_window.title("Grocery Store Manager")
        new_window.resizable(FALSE,FALSE)

        main_head = ctk.CTkLabel(new_window,text="Enter the details:")
        main_head.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=15,pady=20)

        self.product_name_tv = StringVar()
        self.product_price_tv = IntVar()
        ctk.CTkLabel(new_window,text="Product Name: ").grid(row=1,column=0,padx=25)
        self.product_name_input = ctk.CTkEntry(new_window,placeholder_text="Productname",textvariable=self.product_name_tv)
        self.product_name_input.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=20,pady=15)

        ctk.CTkLabel(new_window,text="Product Price: ").grid(row=2,column=0,padx=25)
        self.seller_mobile_input = ctk.CTkEntry(new_window,placeholder_text="Productprice",textvariable=self.product_price_tv)
        self.seller_mobile_input.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=15,padx=15) 

        pn = self.product_name_input.get()
        pp = self.product_price_tv.get()

        def add_products_to_db(pn,pp):
            print(pn,pp)
        

        ctk.set_default_color_theme("blue")
        self.submit_product_btn = ctk.CTkButton(new_window,text="Submit",command=lambda : add_products_to_db(pn,pp))
        self.submit_product_btn.grid(row=3,column=1,padx=20,pady=15)
```

Comment: You're setting `pn` and `pp` before the user has had a chance to fill in the entries.

Comment: `self.product_name_input.get()` should be `self.product_name_tv.get()` to use the `StringVar`. But still, you have to wait for the user to fill in the fields and click the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

- You are retriving `self.product_name_input` and `self.product_price_tv` immediately after creating the entry widgets, at that point user has not entered any values, so you are getting empty strings `''` and `0` as the values.
- you need to move the lines `pn = self.product_name_input.get()` and `pp = self.product_price_tv.get()` inside the `add_products_to_db` function. This way, the values will be retrieved when the user clicks the `Submit` button.

```py
def add_products_to_db():
        pn = self.product_name_input.get()
        pp = self.product_price_tv.get()
        print(pn,pp)

ctk.set_default_color_theme("blue")
self.submit_product_btn = ctk.CTkButton(new_window,text="Submit",command=add_products_to_db)
self.submit_product_btn.grid(row=3,column=1,padx=20,pady=15)
```

Edited: change reference of `command` option.

Comment: Note that you need to change the `command` option of the button to call the function without arguments.

Comment: @acw1668 nice catch, updated!